# Load jQuery very last

Tags: jquery, load, document-ready

I am using some jQuery to change some text etc... It works perfectly if I test in console. However, when live on site it seems to be overridden by some other code from external page that loads as the last thing on the page. How can I override this external code and make my jQuery load as the very last?

I tried loading script defer, $(window).load but neither seems to work.

**The code I am trying to use:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
         if ($('body.admin_page_wcpv-vendor-order').length > 0)
   {
    $('img#hdfvr-loading-img').attr('src', '/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/358.svg');
    $("#hdfvr-submit-btn").attr('value', '2. Forbered videoen');



    }
});
```

**I've even tried with .load:**

```
jQuery(window).load(function($){
         if ($('body.admin_page_wcpv-vendor-order').length > 0)
   {
    $('img#hdfvr-loading-img').attr('src', '/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/358.svg');
    $("#hdfvr-submit-btn").attr('value', '2. Forbered videoen');



    }
});
```

Comment: "it seems to be overridden" - how can you tell it's being overridden? If this is a website where you're able to run Javascript on, why are you not able to adjust the order that the scripts load in?

Comment: I think it's overridden because I see a quick flash of text being changed. It goes to fast for me to read it tho. - How can I adjust the order? Please note that the js I'm "fighting against" is an external script... I've tried loading my own js both defer and async bot neither seemed to solve my problem.

Comment: What do you mean with "external script"? Presumably you put it there (manually or through a Wordpress plugin). You should never run Javascript on your website if you don't know what it is or where it's coming from. Figure out what script it is, then figure out where it's coming from. That should show you where to add your script to make it load after the other script.